Question about lineal transformation of dimension finite.
I know that if we have a $T:V\to W$ is a lineal injective transformation  and $V,W$ has finite dimension, then $T$ has to be an isomorphism.
But, if we consider $T:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ given by $T(x)=(x,x)$ that is a lineal injective transformation but is not surjective, so is not isomorphism. And, $\Bbb R,\Bbb R^2$ has finite dimension. So, why this is not fail with theorem?
I dont know if my question is dumb, but thanks for asking.

You've just provided a counter-example to the aforementionned statement.

You forgot that $V$ and $W$ need to have the same dimension. Otherwise, the statement is clearly false.

See this post for the correct statement, i.e., what Mark said. The duplicate gives the map $T(x)=(x,0)$, which obviously is not surjective.
